# Spring config xml files management, db connection info

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

maven module spring application.

1 module is a spring mvc application, another is a non-web but spring managed application.

In my project root, I have:

```
/src/main/conf
```

This folder contains my non-web managed spring xml configuration.  I added this folder to my class path in intellij.

1. IntelliJ doesn't pickup the file correctly, meaning I don't get code completion or anything (allot of the names etc. are in bold red i.e. intellij is telling me something is wrong).  Can this be fixed somehow?
   I have kept my spring mvc config file inside its module (not in the conf folder) because the code completion doesn't work and it's a pain to work with without the IDE helping.  But it makes managing things during deployment harder.
2. In both of my spring config files (for the web app and non-web app), I have my dataSource settings hard-coded in the file, I want to extract this somehow into a properties file, how can I do this?

Comment: In the configuration files do you have only different attribute values, or also different bean declarations?

Comment: They shouldn't be treated the same as both have different needs.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can have different spring configuration files all in the same folder, just you need to use different names form them. So, I would use src/main/resources instead to create a new folder in the maven project structure. You will avoid problems.

2- Datasource in both files? why? If you have already two spring configuration files, I would create a third one (application-context-dao.xml) and share the dataSource. How to move properties to a configuration file? [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735405/980472).