# How to access properties from settings.xml to spring.xml and pom.xml to spring.xml

Tags: spring, maven

I am new to maven spring.I have two questions.

1. How to access property set in settings.xml to spring.xml
2. How to accesss property set in pom.xml to spring.xml

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to replace them permanently in the xml (in final jar) or do you want just to pass the value during tests?

Comment: I want to use property from setting.xml or pom.xml to spring.xml

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730755/using-maven-settings-xml-properties-inside-spring-context?rq=1

Comment: Yes.but they have used property file.I want fetch it from property element of pom xml

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter your resources, a maven term that means replacing property placehoders in one file with values from your maven pom. To do this you use the [resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) in your build configuration.